# How to wrap modal into service to make sure only one modal open

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs-ui/bootstrap,  want to only one modal window opening , and close other modal before open it. By call "$('.modal').modal('hide')" only works for regular bootstarp modal, but not sure how to made it by angularjs-ui, it looks hard to call dismiss method in other modal's.

And I need keep modal window do not keep status when showing each time, in other words, all controls lost value after hide. So "$('.modal').hide()" also do not works for me.

I create a issue on github, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1173,  but I do not understand how to wrap a modal into a service.

Comment: An example would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a service that keeps track of all the modals that are currently opened. In this service you could keep a reference to any opened modal and close/dismiss it when a call to a new open comes in, perhaps using the $close method.